# jquery, ajax call fails

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

for some reason this code wont work at all and i really have no idea, i made other ajax calls like this and it worked perfectly, but i don't know why this one wont work at all, please help?
no date will arive in the php file at all.

```
$('.1').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'src/rate.php',
        data: 'rate=1&tut=12',
        success: function(msg){
            $('#view_tut_rating_container').html(msg);

        }

    });
});
```

here is also the php file

```
   require '../config/global.php';
require 'functions.php';
if (isset($_GET['rate'] && isset($_GET['tut']))) {
    $rate = security($_GET['rate']);
    $tut = security($_GET['tut']);
    mysql_query("UPDATE tutorials set clicks = clicks+1 where id = '$tut'");
    mysql_query("UPDATE tutorials set rating = rating+'$rate' where id = '$tut'");
    echo getRatingById2($tut);

}
```

Comment: `url: 'file.php?x=1&y=2'` use `data` for POST calls

Comment: @Peter — No. Use `data` for data. Constructing the query string via `data` is perfectly fine. (Although I'd recommend passing an object of data instead of building the query string by hand).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this `.1` is an anchor try canceling the default action by returning false from the .click handler. Also classnames cannot start with a number. You will have to change your code:

```
$('.someClassName').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'src/rate.php',
        data: { rate: '1', tut: '12' },
        success: function(msg){
            $('#view_tut_rating_container').html(msg);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

Also notice the preferred way to pass arguments to the server.

Comment: that .1 is from this <img class = "1" src="img/star.png">

Comment: Alright, then fix it so that it doesn't start with a number: `<img class = "someClassName" src="img/star.png">`.

Answer (score 0):

The class names cannot start with an integer. Basic rule!!! Change your code something to:

```
$(".a1").click(function(){ ... });
```

And change the HTML to:

```
<img class="a1" />
```

Instead of:

```
<img class="1" />
```

As the second one is wrong.

---

Another thing is, giving the `data` value in a preferred format (JSON).

```
data: {rate: '1', tut: '12'},
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code. just now tested and working fine for me.

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){ 
            $('.1').on("click",function(){

                                        alert("test");
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: 'rate.php',
                    data: 'rate=1&tut=12',
                    success: function(msg){
                        $('#view_tut_rating_container').html(msg);

                    }

                });
            });


})
</script>




<input type="button" class="1" value="ss"  />
<div id="view_tut_rating_container"></div>
```

and in your php file `if (isset($_GET['rate'] && isset($_GET['tut'])))`

has to be `if (isset($_GET['rate']) && isset($_GET['tut']))` i guess